# perl - gathering information and selecting only some information from the collected data

Tags: regex, perl

I am collecting information from one directory. After that I am only filtering the data I want. Here is my code:

```
sub info { 
  my @files = `ls -l $path_to_dir`;                
  chomp @files;    
}
```

The array has all the information like the following: `@files = ("D1", "K1", "ABC","FD_HTML")`

Now, I want just the file names inside $path_to_dir starting with D1, K1, D0, K0, A0 etc. Can you please suggest on how to filter the data like D0, D1, K0, A0  from the gathered information from $path_to_dir which is stored in array "@files". Now, from that array I just want to store data like D0, K0, K1, A0 in a different array. How to do that?

Comment: You need to reformat your code using the code option as it isn't clear

Comment: Based on your other questions, that you've never accepted, or provided feedback, with very similar feel, it seems you have been informed of `grep`. Also, your code won't run. `my @files = ls -l $path_to_dir` seems to be some kind of perl pseudo-code. Please edit your question to include code you have tried to run.

Comment: @KeepCalmAndCarryOn: Is the edit fine now? Thanks,

Comment: @user2498830 Spaces as in when you press the spacebar =P

Comment: @user2498830: I hope this looks okay now, Thanks, Jerry!

Comment: @mikew: That was little different question. In that question, I wanted to grep non required data and the code that worked was not I want in this one. In this, I want to grep for only on files that I want like D0, K1 etc and that too with pattern matching and store only that required data in an array.

Comment: you just answered your own question. use grep. my @new_files = grep(/^[A-Z][0-9]$/, @files); perldoc -f grep

Comment: @mikew: Oyeah, it worked. Thanks :) Can you please share the link for good pattern matching and how to implement it properly?I want to go through some basic regex stuff.Thanks,

Comment: You should not use a shell command and parse output from `ls` when Perl has so many nice options to get and handle file information.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Perl opendir method rather than a shell command. This is both safer and makes you code more portable. Have a look at this page for examples...

http://perlmeme.org/faqs/file_io/directory_listing.html

Pay special attention to the "Find files ending in..." section for an example on how to process specific files matching a regular expression.